# How to detect the "tab" keypress in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I would like to detect the 'tab' keypress in Safari. It already works in IE and Firefox.

The trigger is on keypress. Both firefox and IE return key '9' which is Tab. But Safari looks like to ignore this. Both versions 4 and 5 seem to fail in detecting it. How do i detect it?

Comment: Are you using Safari for Windows or Safari on Mac OS?
I ask cause there are many differences in both versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out what gets detected have a look at [W3Cs Key and Character Codes vs. Event Types](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) page. There you can type and directly see what gets fired.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keyCode` property of the `keydown` event. This will work in all mainstream browsers:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        alert("Tab");
    }
};
```